# In ANTLR4, should I favor Token or ParserRuleContext?

Tags: java, antlr4

Imagine I have the following two grammars:

```
grammar Token;
rule       : 'test' x=Identifier;
Identifier : [a-z]+;

grammar ParserRuleContext;
rule       : 'test' x;
x          : Identifier;
Identifier : [a-z]+;
```

In the former, I can access 'rule' as a public field (value of type Token). In the latter, I access it as a method (value type RuleContext extends ParserRuleContext). The end result is fetched via getText(), so the end result is not different. The question is which *should* I use, and *why*?

Answer (score 0):

The Token variant is more compact.

I see no advantages for the second variant. Yet it seems to me as a matter of taste.